# Are there alternatives to invoke in WPF when passing data from a different thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, task, invoke

I know how to pass data from a worker thread to the main thread via Invoke/BeginInvoke.
I can also pull from a thread safe collection with a timer from the main thread.
I prefer using tasks (Task.Factory.StartNewTask()) and using Backgroundworker with them seams a bit clumsy.

Sometimes the gui is a bit laggy which is due to (Begin)Invoke I assume.
Pulling with a timer also doesn't feel like the right way.
Creating a new Backgroundworker for each new task seams also strange.

Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, memory is shared within an AppDomain, which means all threads can access all data. So, what you're actually doing is controlling access to particular bits of data from particular threads so they don't interfere with each other.

Invoke and BeginInvoke allow you to run code on the UI thread, which is useful because UI controls can only be accessed from the UI thread. BackgroundWorker is another solution, as is SynchronizationContext.

However, they all work by sending known windows messages to the UI message loop. If you call Invoke too often, you send too many messages and the UI thread is swamped which makes the UI "a bit laggy".

If this happens, you must slow down the rate that messages are sent. There are a couple of ways to do this:

1) Call Invoke less frequently: this means waiting for bigger "chunks" of state changes in your background thread before it calls Invoke to update the UI.

2) Use a UI Timer: there is no point in trying to update the UI faster than the human eye can detect. A UI Timer also sends windows messages to the UI message loop, but at a known rate. The Tick handler can then pull the necessary data from shared memory to update the UI.

Both approaches have their strengths and weaknesses. The choice really depends on how easy it is to group state changes in the background thread into bigger chunks, while making sure the UI doesn't miss any state changes.